# Comma use in an intermediate sentence

Tags: commas

Should I use a comma before and after "it seems" in the following sentence?

> "The reason to the financial crisis, it seems, is the greediness of bankers."

Comment: Personally, I avoid the word "it" when it doesn't actually have an antecedent. To make your sentence less inexact and more concrete I suggest you drop the "it". Also, instead of the word "to", you should use the word "for" (The reason FOR  the financial crisis . . .).  Don

Comment: [This link](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reword the sentence as follows:

> I think the reason for the financial crisis is the greediness of bankers.

Or,

> I think the cause of the financial crisis . . ..

Or,

> In my way of thinking, the reason for the financial crisis . . ..

Or,

> I suggest the reason for the financial crisis is . . ..

Or,

> According to Milton Friedman, the reason for the financial crisis . . ..

Or,

> In my humble opinion, the reason for the financial crisis is . . ..

Or,

> From my perspective, the reason for the financial crisis is . . ..